# Live content migration to a separate server for important content

Tags: migrations, backups

My clients are now spending a lot of money daily on creating content on my system. A few hours lost could be quite bad for them, and in turn, for me.

Most of the site is fine on daily backups, but there is a content type I'd like to offload onto a backup server when nodes are created or updated. Is this possible? Preferably sending a node object and related files.

I haven't had an issue in a long time but I'm feeling the stress with their investment.

Comment: How would you be storing the content on the backup server? Just as a text file/images? Or did you mean to another instance of the same drupal website and it would get recreated on there? If something was to happen would you restore the site from your daily backup and then attempt to recreate these pages by copy/pasting from the new backups? Sounds like rather than try and reinvent the wheel you might be better off looking at server redundancy to ensure the whole site is replicated/backed on another server

Comment: I meant another instance, not necessarily up to date with the daily backups, but with the same config. My idea is that daily backups would be the base, but I could use node_export module, or a manual method to transfer any new content since the latest backup, if I ever had to use that backup.

Comment: Dont think there's anything you can easily setup. It would probably involve creating an API endpoint on your backup site that would expect JSON/XML and would create a node and download images from that data. It would also need to be coded to handle updating existing nodes (As you wanted it to happen on node update as well as creation). Then on your live site add a hook_node_update add code to send the node data to your backup sites API.  As mentioned you'd probably be better off trying to schedule automated backups with something like https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

Comment: You've got to [REST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2nHIWlCXSw), it's for the best. To build a nest, to take the quest. To be given just one chance to be the best.

Comment: @LeighMason I will likely do something as you've described. I figured it would be something like that. Feels like such a good contrib though.. Being able to send nodes to another server. Anyways, thanks. I'll make it work as I usually somehow do.

Comment: @NiallMurphy  I just gave you the how to.

Comment: @NoSssweat lol While I'm sure you did in a very clever way, it flew over my head.  Sorry I missed it :p

Comment: @NiallMurphy no prob. You didn't specify your version, but that's for D7 as you can tell, but good for learning anyways. If your site is on D8, Core comes with a REST module that you can use.

Comment: As an alternative to what @NoSssweat suggested: how about using the [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) module to create some ort of custom logging (whereas you define the layout of the logrecords yourself, since the messages created are fieldable entities). And if it is about D7, use its amazing integration with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module ... PS: you only get 1 chance to make a 1st impression ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens you forgot or missed to take into account the `offload onto a backup/external server` part.

Comment: @NoSssweat how about deligating that part of the work to "Message Notify"?

Answer (score -1):

With the [Backup & Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module installed, navigate to: /admin/config/development/backup_migrate/schedule to create & manage database or site file backup schedules:

[image: D8]

Note that there are options to backup the default Drupal database, all of the site files, or just specific Drupal file directories.

Under "Settings" there is an admin section to configure the destination address for the backups at: /admin/config/development/backup_migrate/settings/destination

Schedule a complete site backup daily with hourly database backups. The Backup & Migrate developers have the [NodeSquirrel](https://www.nodesquirrel.com/) service available for offsite backups - but this service only works with the D7 module & is unavailable for D8 currently.

With cPanel, there are better options available now with [cPanel Backups & Backup Tool](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/74Docs/Backup+for+cPanel):

[image: BM]

If you need a more professional backup service, look into [Veeam](https://www.veeam.com/).

Comment: Hi, while this is good information for general backups, you got downvoted by members as the question was about sending data to a separate server immediately as it's created. I already have multiple regular ways of backing up my site.